# How to verify if all objects are selected?

Tags: python, objects

How can I create a Boolean variable that is true when all objects in the scene are selected?

Answer (score 1):

```
len(bpy.context.scene.objects) == len(bpy.context.selected_objects)
```

Comment: Well, nice answer, even if a bit non-verbose :P Can you please add some details?

Comment: Based strictly on looking at the names I'm going to guess that bpy.context.scene.objects is the list of objects in the scene, and bpy.context.selected_objects is the list of selected objects.